# Colors of custom footer created on elementor changes automatically after applying

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I created a custom footer in elementor. After updating, when I checked my website, the color changed completely, both of text and background. I don’t know how it happened, but please help me out.

Footer I created on elementor:- https://prnt.sc/ucmaif

Same footer after applying on the website:- https://prnt.sc/ucmam0

Site URL:- https://smartgadgetpick.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's due to using Global Colors (added in new update).
If you have saved colors in your global colors so you can access them easier, after choosing the color (from Global Colors) click on the color box (which previews the color) to detach the color from Global (the color will not change, it just won't act as global)

Comment: I'll try that. Thank you so much!